# Is there a way to walk dynamically into multidimensional arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

For example:

```
$size = 0;
$array = $array;

$size = 1;
$array = $array[x];

$size = 5;
$array = $array[x][x][x][x][x];
```

I got a $config array that can either have 1 dimension or many. Depending on setting of the var $size the elements I need walk gonna be on that position. If size = 1, I will be looking for $config[1]. If size = 2 I will be looking for $config[1][1] ...

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$foo = $array;
for($i=0;$i<$size;++$i) {
    $foo = $foo[x];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = $array[x][x][x][x][x];
for ($x = 0; $x < 5; $x++) {
  if (!is_array($array[1])) break;
  $array = $array[1];
}
```

You can make infinite loop and reach end of array.